# php cron script not reading arguments from commend line

Tags: php, switch-statement, cron

I have two file.

One is a simple text file that has all the real path link of my scron script with arguments

The other file is my cron script itself.

my contab  text file is simply this:

```
#!/bin/sh 
/usr/bin/php -f /home/path/reports/report.php arg1

/usr/bin/php -f /home/path/reports/report.php arg2
```

The cron script reads the argument in the crontab file and will run accordingly to what argument it is.

report.php --

```
php $args = $argv[1];
 $count = 0;
switch($args){
   case 'arg1':
     code and create certain file .... 
   exit;
   case 'arg2':
         code and create certain file  ... 
   exit;

    }   // <--- this script runs perfectly if I run script manually through putty commend line, meaning it will run exactly what I want depending on what $argv[1]  I put in manual commend line,  BUT doesn't run automatically from crontab script
```

This file does not run and  have no idea why, it runs when I manually run report.php through commend line, it works.

One thing i have noticed and got it to kind of work is by changing the report.php to this:

report.php --

```
$args = $argv[1];
 $count = 0;
switch($args){
   case ($args ='arg1'): // <- just putting the equal sign makes it work
     code and create certain file .... 
   exit;
   case ($args = 'arg2'):
         code and create certain file  ... 
   exit;

    } // <-- this script was a test to see if it had anything to do with the equal sign, surprisingly script actually worked but only for first case no what matter what argv[1] I had, this is not what I am looking for.
```

The problem was it only works for the first case, no matter what argument I put in the text file in crobtab it always run the first case. It's probably because I am stating $args = 'arg1', so it always see it as arg1.

So I tried to make it work by doing this instead:

report.php --

```
$args = $argv[1];
 $count = 0;
switch($args){
   case ($args =='arg1'): // <- == does not work at all....
     code and create certain file .... 
   exit;
   case ($args == 'arg2'):
         code and create certain file  ... 
   exit;

    } // <--- this script runs perfectly if I run script manually through putty commend line, but not automatically from crontab script
```

and this runs nothing, it does not pick up my argument at all, just to note this report.php file with the comparison "==" runs perfectly if I run manually on commend line.

What is going on? Why doesn't the cron script read my argument correctly when I use the "==" to find out my arguments from the crontab file.

Comment: Look at the syntax of the switch statement. `case ($args == 'arg1')` doesn't do what you think it does: it compares `$args` to a boolean.

Comment: @arxanas It amazes me how many people have no idea how to read the `switch` documentation located at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 3):

As for $argv -> "Note: This variable is not available when register_argc_argv is disabled.". I'd suggest to switch to $_SERVER['argv'] and $_SERVER['argc'] (yes, you read correctly) instead of $argv/$argc stuff.

And as for this

```
case ($args ='arg1'): // <- just putting the equal sign makes it work
```

man, you clearly do not understand what you doing and what's the difference between ($args=='arg1') and ($args='arg1')!

--[ code for comment bellow ]----

save this as test.php:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['argv'][1] ."\n";
```

and test it.

```
$ php test.php abd
abd
```

Comment: I have tried using $_SERVER['argv'][1] instead of $argv[1], it still not reading the arguments from the crontab script.

Comment: you seem to do something wrong. See the code in my former answer and test it.

Comment: what I mean to say it doesn't work in auto cron script, it works if I manually run by putty.

Comment: There should be no difference. Got many php scripts cron'ed here and no problem passing arguments. And `-f` is not needed. I'd then suggest to replace your script with test one that would write dump of $_SERVER to the file. Invoke it from cron and see what's there.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first works is because if you use = instead of == you are setting the variable within the if statement.

Try var_dump($argv) and see if anything is assigned to the variable.

Comment: I'm not setting a variable for $args, that's why I am trying so hard to make the comparison == works. If I run the script manually through putty it works fine , I put this in commend line  :  php report.php arg1   <--- this works and when I var_dump it, it shows the correct argument : arg1

Comment: The problem is making it run by reading the arguement from my crontab script, it just doesn't pick up arg1. I don't have access to see the error file on the cron jobs.

Comment: Then the problem must lie in the cron script, and the way it executes the commands - how are you executing your cron script?

Comment: I did a very simple cron page to test, taking out my entire script really and leaving the case to do a simple fwrite. 
  Script runs like this :

Comment: I did a very simple cron page to test, taking out my entire script really and leaving the case to do a simple fwrite. 
 
 Script runs like this :

   define("SRV_RT",realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..')); 
   $args = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
     
switch($args){
      
  case 'arg1':
       $dailyHandle = fopen(SRV_RT.'/reports/testing_arg1.php', 'w+') or die("can't open file"); 
       break;  

case 'arg2':
$dailyHandle = fopen(SRV_RT.'/reports/testing_noarg.php', 'w+') or die("can't open file"); 
break;  
}

fwrite($dailyHandle,'TESTING TESTING TESTING');
fclose($dailyHandle);

Comment: case doesn't work for auto cron scripts, it works for manual commend line

Answer (score 0):

As @arxanas mentions in the comments, your switch is AFU. Read the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). `case` statements already do the equivalent of `$x == [value]`, so you only need to use `case [value]:`.

```
switch($args) {
    case ($args =='arg1'):
        .
        .
        .
        break;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

should be

```
switch($args) {
    case 'arg1':
        .
        .
        .
        break;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: if you look at my first report.php switch and cases, it follows the switch in php manual with the only difference I put exit; instead of switch. I have done it with break; but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `exit` will cause your *entire script* to end. Is this what you want? Or do you just want to `break` out of the switch statement?

Comment: i want the script to end when it finish doing whatever I want in that case, you see I got different cases for different times it need to be done, which is all depending on the arguments. Some case do have breaks in it since it have variables set for that case to be used in a loop later on. I did test it out and put break; in all my cases and deleted the exit;, thought perhaps it was the exit; that was causing my problem since it was ending my entire script, it still didn't work.

Comment: @user1612672 OK, then it's fine. In this case, the problem is the value you're passing into the `switch`. What displays when you `echo $arg1;`?

Comment: i can't see what it echos when it run automatically, but if I run manually for example like this : php report.php arg1, it echos arg1 back

Comment: I pretty much give up trying to make the switch work depending on the $argv[1], I'm just going to make a separate cron script for each case instead. Those script seem to work fine automatically. I still would like to make my original idea work, so if anyone got any idea where it went wrong it be nice to solve this.

Comment: You can have your cron scheduler email you with the output, FYI.